# Autolayout frame update in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have a custom subview defined this way:

```
class CustomSubview:UIView {

 let contentView = ContentView(frame: .zero) //ContentView is another custom subview

 override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupContentView()
}

 private func setupContentView() {
    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant:10).isActive = true
    contentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.clipsToBounds = true
    contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
     NSLog("Contentview frame \(contentView.frame)")
}
}
```

The problem is even after calling layoutIfNeeded, the frame is still CGRect.zero. Why is that? How do I ensure bounds to be updated immediately?

Comment: Calling `layoutIfNeeded()` on your `contentView` will not change its size since it lays out _its_ subviews. The frame of this view should be correct once its _superview_ (the class you are showing in this example) performs a layout update in its own `layoutSubviews` method.

Comment: So what do I need to do to update the frame immediately?

Comment: I would set it manually and leave on `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` **but** I would also doubt at the same time that I really need to know the frame upon view initialization... If you want to make sure that position and sizes are correct, you have to do so _after_ `layoutSubviews`

Comment: So basically I override layoutSubviews, and perform any actions that depend on contentView frame after calling super.layoutSubviews?

Comment: Correct. Be careful though cause it might get called multiple times.

Comment: @DeepakSharma - why do you care if the frame is `CGRect.zero` at that point? If you are using constraints correctly, auto-layout will handle the frame size changes. If you are *not* using constraints correctly, you need to show the code that you are using that's causing problems at that point.

Comment: @DonMag I use contentView.bounds.width to calculate number of thumbnails to put in contentView. I add thumbnails in the same setup to contentView. I get divide by 0 error!

Comment: `contentView.layoutIfNeeded()` No. Do not perform layout in `viewDidLoad`. The whole point of autolayout constraints is that they will be obeyed when layout happens in the natural course of things. Don't try to subvert that.

Comment: As a workaround, I am doing things in viewWillAppear:...can one hope things will be always natural in viewWillAppear?

Answer (score 0):

In `CustomSubview` class, implement:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    NSLog("In layoutSubviews() - Contentview frame \(contentView.frame)")
}
```

That's where you have the actual frame. Note that it will be called anytime your instance of `CustomSubview` changes, such as on device rotation (assuming you have it set up to change size when its superview changes size).

So, you would want to calculate how many "thumbnails" you want to display, and either add or remove them as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

to

```
contentView.setNeedsLayout()
layoutIfNeeded()
```

You need to tell the `CustomSubview` object to lay itself out again, not just the `contentView`.